# how to calculate $\cos(\pi+i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've come across a problem asking us to calculate $\cos(\pi+i)$, and express it in the way of $a+bi$, where both a and b are real numbers. How to tackle questions like this? Thanks.

Comment: Use the hyperbolic sine and cosine.

Comment: [Sum-to-product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)

Comment: @Bye_World I used the one for cosine, but the result still includes cosine and sine. Dunno how to get rid of it.

Comment: $\sin(\pi)$ and $\cos(\pi)$ should be *pretty* easy to evaluate.  $\cos(i)$ requires you to know the [relationship between the trig and hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Hyperbolic_functions_for_complex_numbers).

Comment: yes but then there left $sin(i) and cos(i)$

Comment: There should be no $\sin(i)$ left.

Comment: Then I used the fact that $i=e^{i\pi/2}$

Comment: Easy, $\cos(pi + i) = \cos((p+1)i) = \cosh(p+1)$.

Comment: @Hubble sorry for the confusion, it's $\pi$, not pi

Comment: @J.doe It was a joke to make you realize that formatting is important :-)

Comment: $cos(\pi+i)=cos(\pi)cos(i)+sin(\pi)sin(i)=cos(i)$, then how to proceed from there?

Comment: @Hubble My bad.. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard identities for sine and cosine continue to hold in the complex numbers, so
$$
\cos(\pi+i)=-\cos i=-\frac{e^{i^2}+e^{-i^2}}{2}=-\frac{e+e^{-1}}{2}
$$
because
$$
\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
By cosine addition formula, we have that $\cos \pi+i=\cos \pi \cos i - \sin \pi \sin i = - \cos i$. Now you can use the exponential definition of cosine to convert cos i into the form a + bi.